# How to use lightweight thread in Clojure?

Tags: multithreading, clojure

I was trying to rewrite this Rust code in Clojure:

```
fn main() {
    let nums = [1, 2];
    let noms = ["Tim", "Eston", "Aaron", "Ben"];

    let mut odds = nums.iter().map(|&x| x * 2 - 1);

    for num in odds {
        spawn(proc() {
            println!("{:s} says hello from a lightweight thread!", noms[num]);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the Clojure code that did almost the same with the above mentioned Rust code

```
(def noms ["Tim", "Eston", "Aaron", "Ben"])
(doseq [i (take-nth 2 (rest noms))]
  (println i "says hello from a lightweight thread!"))
```

Except it does not use thread.

1. How to write "lightweight" thread (or something equivalent in Clojure terms)?
2. This code is almost the direct translate from the imperial programming style. What's the idiomatic way to write?

Answer (score 3):

Beware of the terminology: the clojure example using futures doesn't create a lightweight thread but rather a native OS thread. Rust does the same by default but it has a green thread runtime that provides the lightweight semantics. Reference: http://rustbyexample.com/tasks.html

Clojure doesn't support lightweight threads by default but you can create them via the library [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async). So the code would look something like this:

```
(require '[clojure.core.async :as async :refer :all])
(doseq [i (take-nth 2 (rest noms))]
  (go (print (str i " says hello from a lightweight thread!\n"))))
```

The `go` macro above will create a proper lightweight thread *

* The statement wasn't clear as pointed out in the comments so I'll try and clarify: core.async is backed by a Java thread pool, however the `go` macro turns your code into a state machine that uses "parking" instead of "blocking". This just means you can have tens of thousands of go blocks backed by a limited number of real threads.

When using blocking IO however, this benefit is hindered, as explained by the [post](http://martintrojer.github.io/clojure/2013/07/07/coreasync-and-blocking-io/) @hsestupin refers to below.

To understand how core.async manages to have lightweight threads on the JVM, I recommend starting here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3PZMIwXN_g - it's a great video into the internals of the `go` macro.

The macro itself is implemented [here](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/53bf7866f195e6ba247ff7122b99784e66e9f1bb/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async.clj#L369)

Comment: This code using go macro doesn't behave properly. It sometimes print 1 line, sometimes print 3 lines. What's wrong? 
`user=> (doseq [i (take-nth 2 (rest noms))]
  #_=>   (go (print (str i " says hello from a lightweight thread!\n"))))
Ben says hello from a lightweight thread!
nil
user=> (doseq [i (take-nth 2 (rest noms))]
  #_=>   (go (print (str i " says hello from a lightweight thread!\n"))))
Eston says hello from a lightweight thread!
Ben says hello from a lightweight thread!
Eston says hello from a lightweight thread!
nil
user=> 
`

Comment: **The go macro above will create a proper lightweight thread** Are you serious? Can you explain how? Or please give a link to the official documentaion/source dode.

Comment: I recommend you to read this article http://martintrojer.github.io/clojure/2013/07/07/coreasync-and-blocking-io/

Comment: good explanation but just to be ultra-clear, core.async on the JVM is backed by a Java thread pool. when core.async is used in clojurescript (in the browser) it defaults to the JS runtime event-loop as explained in this excellent video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: The article link is broken. Use http://martintrojer.github.io/clojure/2013/07/07/coreasync-and-blocking-io .

Answer (score 2):

You can use `future` to spawn threads. In this case you could do something like:

```
(doseq [i (take-nth 2 (rest noms))]
  (future (print (str i " says hello from a lightweight thread!\n"))))
```

Comment: note the usage of `str` here, otherwise the numbers and the rest of the message can get mixed up among the threads